# Cakephp 1.3 mock authentication

Tags: mocking, cakephp-1.3, simpletest

I am trying to write and test on a controller action.  Here is what I have:

```php
App::import('Component', 'Auth');
App::import('Controller', 'Goals');

class GoalControllerTest extends CakeTestCase {

    function startCase() {
            echo '<h1>Starting Test Case</h1>';
            $this->Goals = new TestGoalsController();
            $this->Goals->constructClasses();
            $this->Goals->Component->initialize($this->Goals);
    }

    function endCase() {
            unset($this->Goals);
            ClassRegistry::flush();
            echo '<h1>Ending Test Case</h1>';
    }

    function startTest($method) {
            echo '<h3>Starting method ' . $method . '</h3>';
            //$this->GoalsController = new TestGoalsController();
            Mock::generate('AuthComponent');
            $this->Goals->Auth = new MockAuthComponent();
    }

    function endTest($method) {
            echo '<hr />';
    }

    function testSetHomepage() {
            //get goal for test
            $sql = "SELECT id FROM goals limit 1";
            $goal = $this->Goals->Goal->query($sql);
            $this->Goals->params = Router::parse('/goals/setHomepage/');
            $this->Goals->beforeFilter();
            $this->Goals->Component->startup($this->Goals);
            $this->Goals->params['url']['goal_id'] = $goal[0]['goals']['id'];
            $this->Goals->params['url']['set_to'] = 1;
            $this->Goals->setHomepage();

            //Mock Auth
            $this->Goals->Auth->setReturnValue('user', 1);


            //check the set
            $sql = "SELECT GoalOnHome.goal_id FROM goals_users as GoalOnHome WHERE GoalOnHome.goal_id = '" . $this->Goals->params['url']['goal_id'] . "' limit 1";
            $result = $this->Goals->Goal->query($sql);

            $expected = false;
            $this->assertEqual(empty($result), $expected);
            unset($this->Goals->params['url']);
    }
}
```

I am trying to mock the authentication components and I get this error when I run the test:

`Unexpected PHP error [Undefined property: MockAuthComponent::$enabled] severity [E_NOTICE] in`

Can someone help me with what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I got rid of that undefined property error by moving the mock genereate to : function startCase() {
                echo '<h1>Starting Test Case</h1>';
                $this->Goals = new TestGoalsController();
                Mock::generate('AuthComponent');
                $this->Goals->Auth = new MockAuthComponent();
                $this->Goals->constructClasses();
                $this->Goals->Component->initialize($this->Goals);
        }  But I am know getting this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method AuthComponent::setReturnValue() in

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. I fixed it by simply setting the property on the Mock object. Additionally, I configured a return value for the `startup`-method - otherwise, the mocked authentication will not work.

```
function startTest() {
    // Set up controller etc.
    // ...
    $this->Goals->Auth = new MockAuthComponent();  
    $this->Goals->Auth->enabled = true; // Should solve your error
    $this->Goals->Auth->setReturnValue('startup', true);
}
```